# How do you model an anonymous user in an existing Rails schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on my first simple Rails app in which users submit sport "tweets" (e.g. "tennis, squash") and the server matches them up with partners. The server will return you a list of SportMatches based on similar tweets and you have different options (e.g. email, SMS) to reply back to someone's tweet and accept him/her as partner. Initially, the modeling was straight forward since: User has_many SportTweets and SportTweet belongs to User. Notifications were simply part of the User, or they could have been modeled as a 1-to-1 relationship to User.

My business requirements changed a little, as now I have anonymous users who can also post SportTweets. Because they don't have an account/profile, they must also submit notifications (e.g. email, SMS) with the tweet. I don't know how to model this the Rails way. SportTweets are now either anonymous, or authenticated-user-posted (AUP). So, now, my SportTweets table will have the following columns:

- type: either "anonymous" or "AUP"
- user_id: only for AUP
- notifications_id: only for anonymous
- sports: for all
- post_date: for all
- post_location: for all
- etc.

There would be a Notifications table. A notification record would belong either to a User, or to a SportsTweet. I guess I would model this with polymorphic associations.

That just doesn't look like the Rails way. Did anyone come across a similar problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of searching and the answer is STI. See The Rails 3 Way - Chapter 9.

Comment: To make this answer more useful please paraphrase what's useful from The Rails 3 Way - Chapter 9. Five years from now when your answer lives on and The Rails 3 Way is out of print and hard to find your answer should still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Devise if you can. I think this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user) might help you.

> In some applications, it's useful to have a guest User object to pass around even before the (human) user has registered or logged in. Normally, you want this guest user to persist as long as the browser session persists.
>
> Our approach is to create a guest user object in the database and store its id in session[:guest_user_id]. When (and if) the user registers or logs in, we delete the guest user and clear the session variable. A helper function, current_or_guest_user, returns guest_user if the user is not logged in and current_user if the user is logged in.

Followed by the code which you might find helpful in that [page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user)